# How to add assembly plugin to SBT build?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm trying to use sbt assembly plugin to compile my scala code. When I package it to snapshot.jar, it works well. But when I try to add assembly plugin and compile it to assembly.jar I got problems. Can anyone help me with it?

```
tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars/hello/hello$ sbt package
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/usr/local/jars/hello/hello/)
[info] Packaging /usr/local/jars/hello/hello/target/scala-2.10/hello_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Oct 23, 2015 10:02:52 AM
```

With `sbt-assembly` I get

```
tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars/hello/hello$ addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"com.eed3si9n"'
```

Answer (score 2):

The command `addSbtPlugin` is not a unix command and can't be run in a *Linux*shell. In general it is an SBT command (or task, not sure right now) and can only be used in SBT. (to try it out, enter SBT console by simply running `sbt` from your shell/bash.

So in **your case**, `addSbtPlugin ....` needs to be placed in a '.sbt' file, preferred place is 'plugin.sbt`, inside your project to add the plugin to your build environment. You are kindly referred to [SBT tutorial pages on using plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Using-Plugins.html)

and in general

- [SBT Tutorial](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/index.html)
- [SBT Reference Doc](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

On the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) project page there's a rather clean and easy explanation on how to install/use the plugin.

Just to get you up to speed, you only need to add the following snippet to your `$PROJECT_ROOT/project/assembly.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.0")
```

and then from a shell you can start the assembly phase like this:

```
$ cd $PROJECT_ROOT
$ sbt assembly
```

in order to avoid dependencies problems (as explained in the sbt-assembly project page) it's better to use sbt version >= 0.13.6. You can enforce this by placing the following in `$PROJECT_ROOT/build.properties`:

```
sbt.version=0.13.8
```